# Increase space between icons in xfce notification area

Tags: xfce

Is it possible to increase the space between the icons in the *xfce notification area*? I want to change the spacing so that the *notification area* looks like the *indicator plugin* on the left (see the picture). Right now it looks horrible with this inconsistency.

Maybe there is a solution in the [xfce forums](http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6844), but i hope that i don't have to compile the whole notification plugin only for such a small change.

[image: xfce-panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the current notification area doesn't support this sort of setting, hence apart from compiling it on your own, you can file a feature bug for it to become run-time adjustable.

Comment: I filed a feature request at XFCEs Bugzilla.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to check in the notifications area settings. It is called something like (my xfce is not in english) "display in a frame" and it increase a little bit the space. But there is no way to set the space...